# Content assist in Android xml file for android:singleLine in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Content assist (ctrl-space) work for the

```
<EditTextPreference
```

but for the following singleLine and for value "true" or "false" it does not work?

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Get the message: Content Assist not available for the current location

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 ...
 <EditTextPreference
    android:hint="your@address.com"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:key="@string/key_dest_email"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_dest_email" />
 ...
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I open the xml file with "Android Common XML Editor"
Is it suppose to work?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you cant ctrl-space for singleLine ?

Comment: Yes and for the value "true"

Comment: So you able to get the value false ?

Comment: Can't get singleLine or true or false. Neither value.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

They dont support those.

Comment: OK got your point, but android:hint works for EditTextPreference, but does not show up as content assist? Why is this?

Comment: hint is a text so it wouldnt have anything to assist you with :)

Comment: True, but I mean the reserved word "hint" itself. When the cursor is at android: